# CC110L refusing packages - only reset helps

Tags: c, microcontroller, wireless, msp430, texas-instruments

I've got the following setup:
I use several TI MSP430F5529 Launchpads with the Anaren AIR Boosterpack (Basically just a CC110L) that communicate with each other, one of them being connected to a computer via UART.

Now, sometimes (every few thousand packages or so, randomly, not really reproduceable) one of the transcievers (not reproduceable) refuces to accept packages. When looking at the SPI communication I see that the GDO0 pin goes high, as it should, but when requesting the number of bytes in the RXFIFO the transciever returns '0'. The status byte i get is 16, meaning that the transciever is in RX mode but the RXFIFO is empty as opposed to 31 = 16 (RX Mode) + 15 (15 or more bytes available).

I currently suspect that the transciever rejects the package on hardware level (meaning e.g. a failed CRC check) - BUT all the other nodes with identical hardware and identical software are able to recieve the package, and so is/are the node(s) in question after a reset.

As far is i see it, none of the problems mentioned in the errata sheet fit the description - any ideas?

Cheers,
David

Comment: Please see my answer below. Are you flushing your fifo? If you want to go down the path you've already established, have a look at CC1101.c to see how the driver implements communicating with the radio.

Comment: Since this issue is years old I've got no idea what the actual solution was in the end but I did end up modifying the library I was using (LarsRF) because it was originally written for a slower chip and there was a timing issue.
https://github.com/mobilars/LarsRF/commit/2d9024c11c4ce2cd47bd18cf9dddb6b733c1b2a0

Answer (score 1):

The transceiver has a few issues with it that are stated in the errata: http://www.ti.com/lit/er/swrz037/swrz037.pdf

I have dealt with the CC110L extensively and have authored a driver/library that works with the exact booster pack that you're interested in. The implementation should handle implementing solutions to the issues in the errata. Please have a look at the following protocol: https://github.com/AnarenAIR/BaseLink

The files of interest for you are under /Source/Physical/Driver and /Source/Physical/Module. The Driver is a generic CC1101(or L) wrapper that requires a few functions (SPI/GDO hardware-specific) to be implemented. The Module defines configuration that you should be using with your certified Anaren module.

Do let me know if you go down this path and if you need help getting started. You could always use the code as is (starting from one of the examples) as it implements a low-power multiple end-point to gateway protocol configuration.

Comment: Currently I'm using a version of [LarsRF](http://github.com/mobilars/LarsRF) which i ported and cleaned up. As far as I see the SPI Clock Sync could fit, but as I said, when using a logic analyzer I can verify the SPI results I get on the microcontroller, the transciever clearly states that its RXFIFO is empty.
Currently i implemented a workaround that detects such a case and simply resets the transciever, but as soon as i get to it I'll see if the issue also occurs when using your code.